# I can't sign up for Meta newsletter

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, newsletter

For the past two days I have been trying to sign up for the Meta newsletter from the box on the Meta Stack Exchange site. I get this error every time.

[image]

Please note that signing up from the newsletter page works. I am asking this to bring the bug to the devs attention.

Comment: I signed up on the [Newsletters](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters) page and didn't have a problem. I'm using Windows 10 with Edge.

Comment: @JakeSymons: I can also sign up from the newsletter page. I asked this to let the developers know there is something wrong.

Comment: Meta as in here on Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: @AdamLear, yes. Here on Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

A small typo snuck into the partial view there. It'll be fixed in the next prod build (later this afternoon).

Thanks for the report!

Comment: I see there was already a build today on MSE... two builds in one day?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Uh, why not? We build when we need to and/or feel like it.

Comment: Think I remember a dev once telling Meta builds are once every day or two days, usually. Might be remembering wrong though. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, that doesn't make sense. MSE/MSO are built as a prerequisite to full prod builds.

Comment: Looks like the bug is back, can you please check again?

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard Different issue (probably). Dean's looking into it.