# Signing up for newsletter error

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, newsletter

I was on Money.SE when I saw an ad for the newsletter, when I tried signing up It came up with an error:

[image]

> there was a problem signing up for the newsletter
>   please try again later

So I decided that I'd do it another time, while on Graphicdesign.SE (which I *already* signed up for - and **never** get the notification/ad to do so, I saw the ad, and just for the heck of it I decided to click sign up - same error)

[image]

Also checked a few random sites, and they all show it

Travel

[image]

Comment: Probably a bug introduced by the fix to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306069/6-questions-in-previous-weeks-no-can-you-answer).

Comment: Related [I can't sign up for Meta newsletter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304838/312043)

Answer (score 2):

Fix has been pushed to production. More details in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306181/267572)!